# How to connect favicon to a website in yew.rs?

Tags: html, yew

I am creating a website through a framework "Yew.rs " and I can't connect favicon.ico.

I tried to connect it with this method:

```
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"><!-- 32×32 -->
</head>
```

but it doesn't work. Can you tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding favicon.ico to the `src` folder and linking to it in the index.html adding:

```
<link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="./src/"> 
<link rel="icon" href="./src/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

This way you can link any folder and it will be copied to the `dist` folder.

Answer (score 1):

When favicon.ico in the frontend package root modify *head* block of index.html like this:

```
 <head>
    <link rel="icon" data-trunk href="/favicon.ico" />
 </head>
```

You were just missing *data-trunk*